# How to format a string in a linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following code

```
IQueryable<string> customers = 
    from Customers in db.Customers
    where Customers.CstCompanyName.Contains(prefixText) && Customers.CstInactive == false
    select Customers.CstCompanyName + " (Phone: " + Convert.ToInt64(Customers.CstPhone).ToString("###-###-#### ####") + ")";
```

This is a call to my entity framework. I am returning a phone number from the database. I am trying to format it in the given format string.  Unfortunately, when I run this, I receive the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

So my question is how do I return this database object as a formatted string?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the result to be an `IQueryable` ? Can't you just get an `IEnumerable<string>` by using `var customers = ...` ?

Comment: Don't. Have the database deal with data; have presentation code deal with presentation.

Comment: In the end, it is being returned as a string[], so whatever will accomplish this. What I am currently doing is string[] cst = customers.ToArray();   So I'm not quite sure if it needs to be IQueryable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would perform the *querying* in the database, but the *formatting* locally:

```
var customers = db.Customers
                  .Where(c => c.CstCompanyName.Contains(prefixText))
                  .Select(c => new { c.CstCompanyName, c.CstPhone })
                  .AsEnumerable() // Switch to in-process
                  .Select(c => c.CstCompanyName + 
                               " (Phone: " +            
                               Convert.ToInt64(Customers.CstPhone)
                                      .ToString("###-###-#### ####") + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way, but I have wanted to use something I'm comfortable with. If you are using entity framework and load it then you can place the String.Format in the LINQ query.

```
Dim ds as Entity = New Entity()
    ds.FinancialInstitutionTransactions.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.TransID).Load()

    Dim openLoad = From tr In ds.FinancialInstitutionTransactions.Local
                   Select TransDate = String.Format("{0:d}", tr.Date),
                   tr.Number,
                   tr.ToFrom,
                   Debit = If(tr.Debit = 0, " ".ToString(), String.Format("{0:N}", tr.Debit).ToString()),
                   Credit = If(tr.Credit = 0, " ".ToString(), String.Format("{0:N}", tr.Credit).ToString())
```

You need to reference System.Data.Entity to load, but then it is easy to format the results any way you want.

I hope this will help someone.
I know this is in vb.net but it would not be to hard to convert to c#.