# entity framework query select new concat

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, concatenation

how i can do something like this? i believe the problem is for the concatenation in the "select".

```
var respaldos = db.Respaldoes.Where(x => x.type == "Backup")
    .Where(x => x.start_time >= _desde && x.start_time <= _hasta)
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.start_time.Year,
        x.start_time.Month,
        x.start_time.Day
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        periodo = x.Key.Day + "/" + x.Key.Month + "/" + x.Key.Year,
        objetos = x.Sum(y => y.bytes_processed)
    });

foreach (var obj in respaldos)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dicciconario = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dicciconario.Add("periodo", obj.periodo.ToString());
    dicciconario.Add("objetos", obj.objetos.ToString());
}
```

i get an error when run the app, the error is in the "foreach"

> Error:
>   No se pudo convertir el tipo 'System.Int32' al tipo 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities sólo admite la conversión a tipos de enumeración o primitivos de EDM.

I try whit:

```
.Select(x => new
{
    periodo = x.Key.Day.ToString() + "/" + x.Key.Month.ToString() + "/" + x.Key.Year.ToString(),
    objetos = x.Sum(y => y.bytes_processed)
});
```

I get other error:

> LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método System.String ToString() del método, y este método no se puede traducir en una expresión de almacén.

Comment: Please, replace original error messages with translated to English...

Comment: I'd change it:     `.GroupBy(x => new{ x.start_time.Year, x.start_time.Month, x.start_time.Day }).Select(...);` to `GroupBy(x => x.start_time).Select(grp=>new{periodo = grp.Key, objectos = grp.Sum(y=>y.bytes_processed)});`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a string in a linq expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535153/how-to-format-a-string-in-a-linq-expression)

Comment: Translation: `Error: Could not convert type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports conversion Enumeration or primitive types of EDM.`  Second Error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the System.String ToString () method of the method, and this method can not be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to group by a date without the time component. EF has a function for that: DbFunctions.TruncateTime:

```
var respaldos = db.Respaldoes.Where(x => x.type == "Backup")
    .Where(x => x.start_time >= _desde && x.start_time <= _hasta)
    .GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.start_time))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        periodo = x.Key, // Now a DateTime value
        objetos = x.Sum(y => y.bytes_processed)
    });
```

After this, you can do

```
Dictionary<DateTime, int> dicciconario =
   respaldos.ToDictionary(x => x.periodo, x => x.objetos);
```